# How can I set the draggable area of my Vaadin widgets

Tags: drag-and-drop, vaadin7

I'm trying to create a simple Dashboard with dragable components in it and I'm a bit stumped on one problem. If I wrap my draggable 'widget' in DragAndDropWrapper and set my layout to recieve drag and drop events, two things happen which I don't like from a UI perspective:

1. The whole area of the layout behind, turns blue (for a while) when I drag things (widgets, files, whatever) over it. How do I turn that off - is that a theme thing?
2. The entire Widget's area is draggable - this is a problem if I have say, other UI components inside the widget which respond to drag events.

How can I set the draggable area of my widgets? I still want the entire wrapped component to display when I drag, but I only want the drag even to occur when I drag, say, the title bar of the widget's panel.

I think my workaround for the time being is to just make a small area of the widget draggable but I don't think that will be a) easy or b) look nice (because when you drag the widget it will just draw it's dragable area - the title bar, say).

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance.

Ac